# intermittently get org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:

Tags: hibernate, spring

I am using Spring-3.0.5 and Hibernate-3 for a project that I am working on.
I intermittently get "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: " for only the "user_roles" domain table and that too only when I try to insert a record in that table. All the domain objects **use** the "*javax.persistence.Entity*" and **not** "*org.hibernate.annotations.Entity*", which is generally the cause of this error. The "sessionFactory" bean has been provided the value of "*packagesToScan*". Cleaning and building the project has not helped. 
Surprisingly when deploying to Tomcat I do see the following lines on the console :

```
[AnnotationBinder] Binding entity from annotated class:  UserRole

[EntityBinder] Bind entity UserRole on table user_roles
```

just like for all other domain classes.

(This question seems to be an exact copy of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257743/i-get-this-error-org-hibernate-mappingexception) which has not been answered yet.)

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed this one.
The problem was with my code. I had saved the user object and was saving the associated user_roles separately without updating the user object i.e. i did session.save(userRoles) without doing user.setUserRoles(userRoles). I now changed the code to first setting the userRoles in user and then just saving the user object which saves the user roles as well.
Wish the hibernate was a bit more consistent in behavior and the error message a bit friendlier :)

Thanks.